# SQL Server data access from C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sql-server-2008, bltoolkit

We are developing our ERP application in C# and SQL Server 2008. For accessing data, we are using "BLToolkit", but some developers are using ADO.net, LINQ etc.

My question is which is best for accessing data?

Comment: did you consider using Entity Framework , working with data will be much easier

Comment: Is it Fast Data Processing when compare to Bltoolkit ,ADO.net etc ???

Comment: If you want to create your own queries then I would suggest using ADO.NET. You'd be building it on your own unlike in other frameworks such as EntityFramework (LINQ). You'd best ask your team if you want to finish the project ASAP since ADO.NET will take a bit of time to code. As for the performance, you can use a stop watch to test but it all boils down to the query you executed whether it is optimized or wrong in so many different levels.

Comment: I recommend to use ADO.NET.

Comment: what is the difference between ADO.net and BLToolkit ???  any advantage and disadvantage ???

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Linq2DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) insted of BLToolkit. It is a successor of BLToolkit which is not actively developed any more. I'm using Linq2DB at work on production projects and also on all my personal projects, and can really recommend it. It is pretty similar to BLToolkit but with many new features like *async* methods, better support for custom expressions and many more.